# Abstracting the functionality of enum

Tags: java, enums, interface

I have 2 enums which look similar:

```
public enum enum1{
     A(1,1),
     B(2,2);
     private final int x,y;
     enum1(int x,int y){
         this.x=x;
         this.y=y;
     }
     int func(){ return this.x+this.y; } 
}


public enum enum2{
     C(3,3),
     D(4,4);
     private final int x,y;
     enum2(int x,int y){
         this.x=x;
         this.y=y;
     }
     int func(){ return this.x+this.y;} 
}

public class test{

    void method(enum1 e){ /*something using func*/ }

    void method(enum2 e){ /*something using func*/ }
}
```

How do I abstract the functionality of these enums in an interface and use only one method in the test class instead of two by passing the interface.

Edit: I don't want the enums to be merged. I need separate enums.

Comment: Well, create an interface and make the two enums implement it?

Comment: The implementation of func is same in both enums.If more such enums are added , then the function needs to be implemented multiple times and I dont want to do that

Comment: Since the function relies on private fields, it needs to be rewritten. If it's a complex function, you can write a static method somewhere which implements all logic based on parameters. But you can't access private members without writing a specific method.

Comment: Do you have to use enums? If you used standard classes, you could have an abstract base class where you could put the common behaviour.

Comment: I have to use enums . Because in the real use case I dont just have 2 instances like A,B . I have nearly fifty instances.

Comment: Did any of the answers solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

One thing is for sure: as long as `x` and `y` are `private` and there's no way to read them from outside the class - you would have to implement the same method for each `enum`. If you allow the reasonable change to add accessors to these fields in the enums, then you can use an interface's `default` method to implement the umbrella behavior:

```
interface Addable {

    int getX();
    int getY();

    default int add() {
        return getX() + getY();
    }
}

enum Enum1 implements Addable {
    A(1, 1), B(2, 2);

    private final int x, y;

    Enum1(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    @Override
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

Then you can make a call like `Enum1.B.add()` which will give `4`. As for your test class:

```
public class Test {
    void method(Addable e) { e.add(); }
}
```

is now valid for anything that implements `Addable`.

If you're worried about bloating the code, I recommend using [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org):

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
enum Enum1 implements Addable {
    A(1, 1), B(2, 2);

    @Getter
    private final int x, y;
}
```

**Note:** type names should start with an uppercase. `enum1` and `test` shoud be `Enum1` and `Test`.

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface that is implemented by each enum, only 'problem' the method must be public:

```
public interface Inter {
    public void func();
}

public enum Enum1 implements Inter {
    A(1,1),
    B(2,2);
    private final int x,y;
    Enum1(int x,int y) {
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
    }
    @Overwrite
    public int func() { return this.x+this.y; } 
}


public enum Enum2 implements Inter {
    ...
    @Overwrite
    public int func() { ... }
}

public class Test {

    void method(Inter e) {
        // something using func
        int sum = e.func();
    }
}
```